# I have directories named pack1 - pack255. What command could I use to remove pack1-55?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Something like >rm pack*{1,2,3,4,??}  and then just remove the last 5 in list format?
I am very new to this, so still getting to grips with the syntax!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ echo rm -rf pack{1..55}
rm -rf pack1 pack2 pack3 pack4...
```

If that works, you can remove the `echo`:

```
$ rm -rf pack{1..55}
```

If it doesn't, you may have to set *braceexpand*:

```
$ set -o braceexpand
```

Then try it again.

Don't forget, if you're removing directories, you need the `-r` for recurse parameter of the `rm` command.